# How can I generate a unique, predictable, repeatable, non sequential alphanumeric identifier?

Tags: dart, pseudocode

I have to generate identifiers composed of four alphanumerical characters, e.g. B41F.

I have the following requirements:

1. Each identifier must be unique (there is no central location to lookup existing identifiers)
2. The identifier must not be obviously sequential (e.g. 1A01, 1A02)
3. It must be predictable
4. It must be repeatable using solely the identifier index (on two different environment, the Nth identifier generated, which has index N, must be the same)

The problem is generic to any language. My implementation will be done in dart.

I think this could be done with a PRNG and some LUT, but I could not find any implementation or pseudo-code that respects requirement 4) without replaying the whole sequence. Also, some PRNG implementation have a random component that is not guaranteed to be repeatable over library update.

How can I achieve this? I'm looking for pseudo-code, code or hints.

Comment: What is requirement 5?  In requirement 4, what do you mean by the "identifier index"?  How many identifiers do you need to generate?  Are your identifiers case-sensitive?  Is this a contrived problem for some programming challenge or interview question?

Comment: I've edited the post, 5 was an error. Index was clarified. It's only uppercase, but that's not really relevant for the problem. This is used to generate serial numbers during manufacturing.

Comment: The size of the identifier space and the number of identifiers you need to generate seems kind of relevant given the pigeonhole principle.

Comment: Why do you dismiss a PRNG for not being able to satisfy requirement #4 without replaying the sequence?  Requirement #4 doesn't make any stipulations about runtime complexity.  Also, regarding library updates, that just means that you cannot rely on a PRNG from a library that does not guarantee long-term reproducibility.  It does not mean you can't implement your own or use a library that does provide such a guarantee.

Comment: Let's simplify it by generating only hexadecimal numbers, that will be enough identifiers. I do not strictly dismiss any PRNG as I have no strong requirement regarding replay. It just seems wrong to generate 10k identifiers again to get #10001 when starting a new batch. I could probably implement my own PRNG (actually the description is exactly the one of a PRGN). I have no experience in PRNG and I thought this is quite a common problem, so I was looking for some good hint on where to start to avoid over-engineering something that may be simpler that I thought.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a PRNG when identifiers must be unique. RNGs do not promise uniqueness. Some might have a long period before they repeat, but that's at their full bit-range, reducing it to a smaller number may cause conflicts earlier.

Your identifiers are really just numbers in base 36, so you need something like `shuffle(index).toRadixString(36)` to generate it.

The tricky bit is the `shuffle` function which must be a permutations of the numbers 0..36^4-1, one which looks random (non-sequential), but can be computed (efficiently?) for any input.

Since 36^4 is not a power of 2, most of the easy bit-shuffles likely won't work.

If you can live with 32^4 numbers only (2^20 ~ 1M) it might be easier.
Then you can also choose to drop `O`, `I`, `0` and `1` from the result, which might make it easier to read.

In that case, I'd do something primitive (not cryptographically secure at all), like:

```
// Represent 20-bit numbers
String represent(int index) {
  RangeError.checkValueInInterval(index, 0, 0xFFFFF, "index");
  var digits = "23456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZ";
  return "${digits[(index >> 15) & 31]}${digits[(index >> 10) & 31]}"
       "${digits[(index >> 5) & 31]}${digits[index & 31]}";
}

// Completely naive number shuffler for 20-bit numbers.
// All numbers made up on the spot.
int shuffle(int index) {
  RangeError.checkValueInInterval(index, 0, 0xFFFFF, "index");
  index ^= 0x35712;
  index ^= index << 15;
  index ^= index << 4;
  index ^= index << 12;
  index ^= index << 7;
  index ^= index << 17;
  return index & 0xFFFFF; // 20 bit only.
}
```

If you really want the full 36^4 range to be used, I'd probably do something like the shuffle, but in base-six arithmetic. Maybe:

```dart
String represent(int index) =>   
    RangeError.checkValueInInterval(index, 0, 1679615, "index")
        .toRadixString(36).toUpperCase();

int shuffle(int index) {
  RangeError.checkValueInInterval(index, 0, 1679615, "index");
  const seed = [1, 4, 2, 5, 0, 3, 1, 4]; // seed.
  var digits = List<int>.filled(8, 0);
  for (var i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    digits[i] = index.remainder(6);
    index = index ~/ 6;
  }

  void shiftAdd(List<int> source, int shift, int times) {
    for (var n = digits.length - 1 - shift; n >= 0; n--) {
      digits[shift + n] = (digits[shift + n] + source[n] * times).remainder(6);
    }
  }

  shiftAdd(seed, 0, 1);
  shiftAdd(digits, 3, 2);
  shiftAdd(digits, 5, 1);
  shiftAdd(digits, 2, 5);
  var result = 0;
  for (var i = digits.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    result = result * 6 + digits[i];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Again, this is something I made up on the spot, it "shuffles", but does not promise anything about the properties of the result, other than that they don't *look* sequential.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I like the simple yet smart way you do the suffle, that's the part I was struggling. Regarding testing it works. However my intuition would say that it does not guarantee uniqueness as some information is shifted and then masked, resulting in a loss of information. How do you know your shuffle does not break uniqueness of the initial index x (20 bit code snippet).

Comment: The value interval of x should also be checked in shuffle, otherwise 0x100000 will cycle to 0x00001 and will silently generate a duplicate.

Comment: The shifting and xor/add+mod actually guarantees that different inputs will give different results, because every operation is *reversible*. (I can prove that, but this comment area is too small for the proof. :)
For good measure, I also checked it (created all indices in the input range and put the resulting strings into a `Set` to check that they were unique.)

Comment: I've just noticed that there is a mistake. 4 chars with 36 possibilities is 4^36, which is way more than 20 bits. Still I could stick to the principle by using only 16 possibilities which makes 4^16 that is 32 bit long.

Comment: It's 36^4, which is more than 2^20, but less than 2^21.

Comment: You're right, my bad. Thanks.