# Given a number in a range, return a predicable but different number also in the range

Tags: javascript, algorithm, random

**Problem**:

I need to generate numerical ids of N length (max 10), have them be unique but not produce them in a humanly predictable sequence.

**Basic example**:

I need an id of length 1 so my available ids are 0-9
I have not generated any ids before so I request id 0 and get (e.g.) 3 in response.
I request id 9 and get (e.g.) 2 in response.

So, each number has a predictable equivalent in the series such that no number will be returned more than once and each number will be used exactly once if N inputs are provided throughout the operation of the program.

If a number is requested outside the available range, this would throw.

**Notes:**

- I will be doing this in JavaScript but the problem is not language specific.
- This example is similar but produced Alphanumeric where i need purely number and it does not fit my other requirements [How can I generate a unique, predictable, repeatable, non sequential alphanumeric identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71349017/how-can-i-generate-a-unique-predictable-repeatable-non-sequential-alphanumeri)

**Constraints**:

- I cannot pre-generate or store the mapping
- The numbers must be whole positive numbers
- I cannot query the "random" series for any numbers already used/assigned.
- I CAN store a salt/secret and keep track of N
- I CAN potentially but not ideally know the last number generated.

Thanks for any input.

I have tried multiple approaches, mostly relating to pre-generating the values on program init but the overhead is too great.

Comment: Have you considered using a Seeded RNG?

Comment: I will look into that now thanks Tkol though i think this may hit a wall when i need to have a predicable input/output if i'm reading it right.

Comment: @TKoL the RNG also needs to produce a unique sequence. Most just produce a uniformly distributed one but that can still produce duplicates.

Comment: I'm afraid anything keeping no more than *one* prior value will be *humanly predictable*.

Comment: I think you can use any algorithm for "random derangement" (there are several questions about such an algorithm here on stackoverflow), but for the random number generator you use a simple pseudo-random number generator with a constant seed, so that the algorithm is deterministic. (I suppose "predictable" in your question is what we usually call "deterministic" in computer science; and "derangement" means "bijection f such that f(n) != n for all n".)

Comment: Voting to reopen. Why was this closed? "Needs debugging details"? But it's not a question about debugging! The problem is quite clear: Given a range [a, b), define a deterministic derangement f : [a, b) -> [a, b) which is sufficiently chaotic that humans can't easily guess the value of f(n) given n.

Comment: @VLAZ he said "predictable" -- I don't know what "predictable and random" means if it doesn't mean exactly the sort of thing a seeded RNG produces. I don't have any other way to interpret those words.

Comment: @VLAZ oh, perhaps I misread your comment. Your criticism is about the fact that the RNG could produce duplicates? Well that's easy to fix -- just don't accept duplicates from the RNG. If it produces a value that it has produced before, just ignore that value and produce the next number. That's fairly straight forward.

Comment: @TKoL "*I need to generate numerical ids of N length (max 10), **have them be unique** but not produce them in a humanly predictable sequence.*" and "*So, each number has a predictable equivalent in the series such that no number will be returned more than once and each number will be used exactly once if N inputs are provided throughout the operation of the program.*"

Comment: @VLAZ yeah, use a seeded random number generator and just reject numbers that have already been produced. Does that not fully answer the question?

Comment: @VLAZ and that's not even the only way to make a seeded RNG produce 10 unique values, if the values can only be 0-9. That's just the most obvious one that came to mind.

Comment: @TKoL Potentially. But also you need to handle collisions. I assume when you request, say, 3 you'd wind the output to the third produced RNG. And if the next is 9, then you also need to skip to 9. But if they both map to the same number, e.g., 7 you need to handle this collision somehow. And for large enough ranges, the cache of seen numbers can also grow. It's a potential solution but I'd say regular RNG + cache is suboptimal and too much work. There are probably better algorithms of scattering the domain to the codomain.

Comment: @Stef BTW, I agree. This is not a debugging question. I implore people to only vote for debugging detail if the question is about code that doesn't work. If the question is "How to" then it's not debugging.

Comment: @Radicis I implemented a little example of what the code could look like with a seeded RNG. https://jsfiddle.net/xkrh61s7/1/

Comment: @Radicis - I'm not an expert in this area, but I strongly doubt it can be done...without leaving gaps. So two questions: 1. Is it okay to leave gaps? If so, how many total unique values do you need across the 10,000,000,000 range (0-9,999,999,999)? 2. "Humanly-predictable" is really wide open. By an average person? By a cryptographer? By a dedicated cracker with 127-core servers to dedicate to the task?

Comment: @TKoL That's just shuffling an array but with more steps. If you really need to use a custom pRNG, then do a [Fisher-Yates shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2450976) but use the seeded RNG as the source of randomness. With that said: 1. OP said shuffling is not a good approach for them. 2. The output is not necessarily 10 single digit numbers. "*I need to generate numerical ids of N length (max 10)*", the function should have input (and thus output) of, for example, `866089534` 3. This should do 1:1 mapping of input to output. Not input -> shuffled 10 digits.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm not an expert on the topic, however, doesn't seem it's impossible to do. Reading [Unique (non-repeating) random numbers in O(1)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/196017) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/196164) and [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41195350) both mention this being possible with a Linear Congruential Generator (LCG) by applying specific bounds to it. As well as few other mention other techniques. Overall, I don't see a huge issue with this in theory. I'm not that good at maths to figure out a good scatter function, though.

Comment: @VLAZ then it's easy enough to take the proof of concept and add a step where the seeded RNG also produces IDs of whatever length he wants. The basic idea works, and nobody's offering more explicit working solutions.

Comment: @TKoL because the question was closed. That's why people haven't been answering it: they couldn't. But also see the bounded LCG idea that I linked above.

Comment: @VLAZ - Very cool stuff... This may be a dupe of that question. Certainly an LCG seems to fit the bill...

Comment: (Please fix title spelling) `I request id 9 and get (e.g.) 2 … each number has a predictable equivalent in the series` as in `get(9)`, or as in *the 9th time calling* `get()`? And make it unmistakable whether N refers to the length of each *id* returned (what about leading zeroes?) or the length of the sequence of identifiers requested.

Comment: @Stef: A derangement is neither necessary (`id(42) //-> 42` is not a problem on its own ) nor sufficient (`id = (n) => (n + 1) % range.length` is obviously too predictable.)

Comment: *The OP literally asked that the number returned be different from the number inputted.*  I don't find that; maybe I'm blind.  A "random derangement" could include the cyclic increment function or something similar.  But agreed, a randomly generated derangement would be unlikely to be that predictable.

Answer (score 1):

"Not human predictable" is going to be quite difficult.  But "not casually human predictable" can probably be done just using the remainder operator and an appropriate multiplier.  Here's one example, using 2-digit ids.

```js
const generator = (digits = 1, seed = 16573, multiplier = 79357) => (i) =>
  String((i * multiplier + seed) % 10 ** digits).padStart(digits, '0')

const getId = generator(2)

console.log(Array.from({length: 20}, (_, i) => getId(i)).join('|'))

//=> 73|30|87|44|01|58|15|72|29|86|43|00|57|14|71|28|85|42|99|56
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

I don't try to implement this:

> If a number is requested outside the available range, this would throw.

That's an easy-enough exercise for the reader.  Instead, in this version, the numbers just loop after the range.

The `multiplier` simply needs to be coprime to the length of the range -- in this case, `100`.  Rather than testing that, I just chose a prime number.  The `seed` is just so we don't start with the multiplier, which might make the pattern more obvious.  It can be any random number, also co-prime to the multiplier.

Users looking at a single id, and not knowing the source code, will not have any idea of the next value.  But if they have a sequence of them, say `['73', '30', '87', '44']`, they could readily discover the pattern.  ("`73` - `30` is `43`.  If I subtract `43` from `30`, I get `-13`, which isn't the same as `87`, but is modulo `100`.  And if I subtract `43` from `87` I get `44`.  Yup, that's it."  And they'd be right; although we're technically adding `57`, it's equivalent to subtracting `43`, modulo `100`.) But that's no longer a casual investigation.

You talk both about a range, as though it might be arbitrary, and about a fixed number of digits.  This does the latter.  But if you wanted values in an arbitrary range, say `150` - `949`, that would involve only a slight change.

Comment: Does this guarantee `i != (i * multiplier + seed) % 10 ** digits` for all `0 <= i < 10**digits`?

Comment: @Stef: No, it doesn't.  I just added a comment to the main question that said that a derangement is neither necessary nor sufficient.  Did I miss such a requirement?

Comment: Oh, I hadn't realised the answer and comment were both from you! I'm a bit distracted today.

Comment: Hmm, after re-reading the questions several times, the only mention of the constraint that `i != getId(i)` is in the title: "Given a number in a range, return a predicable but different number also in the range". So maybe I overinterpreted the word "different" there. We should ask clarification from the OP.

Comment: And I always forget the check the title for requirements!  If it's an important point, then this won't work.  (I don't *think* this offers such a guarantee, but it might.  I'd have to think about it more than I have time for right now.)

Comment: `i = (i * m + s) % t` (where m=multiplier, s=seed, t=power of 10) if and only if there exists a relative integer `q` such that `i (1 - m) + t q = s`. And if 1-m and t are coprime (or more generally iff s is a multiple of gcd(1-m, t)) then this Diophantine equation in unknowns i and q has parametric solution (i(k), q(k)) = (i0 + k t, q0 + k (m - 1)); so yes there must exist a unique k such that i(k) = i0 + k t is in range [0, t). Which means getId has a unique fixed point.

Comment: I'll trust you on this.  My last abstract algebra course was 35 years ago.

Comment: @Stef: But if `s` is prime, does this mean there are no fixed points?  There [are none](https://ramdajs.com/repl/#?const%20generator%20%3D%20%28d%20%3D%201%2C%20s%20%3D%2016573%2C%20m%20%3D%2079357%29%20%3D%3E%20%28i%29%20%3D%3E%0A%20%20%28i%20%2A%20m%20%2B%20s%29%20%25%2010%20%2A%2A%20d%0A%0Aconst%20getId%20%3D%20generator%282%29%0A%0Arange%280%2C%20100%29.find%28i%20%3D%3E%20i%20%3D%3D%20getId%28i%29%29) for the example above.

Comment: Oops. Made a mistake. (i(k), q(k)) = (i0 + k t, q0 + k (m - 1)) are solutions for i (1 - m) + t q = 1. But we want i (1 - m) + t q = s. So the solutions are (i(k), q(k)) = (s i0 + k s t, s q0 + s k (m - 1)) and so there is at most one fixed point but it's very possible there is no fixed-point if no value of k puts s i0 + k s t in range [0, t), especially is s is large.

Comment: Again, I'll have to take your word for that.  It's just been too long.